# How to add onhover tags/ annotations to a network visualized using cytoscape.js

Tags: rstudio, bioinformatics, cytoscape.js, bioconductor, graph-visualization

I am working with Rstudio and to create network visualizations, I am using Cytoscape.
I am unable to find any help document to understand how to add annotations to nodes, onHover of the mouse. 
It has been done on http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/colajs-graph/ for onmouseclick event of nodes. But my requirement is for onHover.

Any help or direction would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is, for example the [tippy.js/popper.js](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper) extension, as mentioned in the cytoscape.js [documentation](https://js.cytoscape.org/), that can handle this feature. With the cytoscape event listeners, you can build these things yourself, but here is an example for your use case:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          content: "data(id)"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "a"
        }
      }, {
        data: {
          id: "b"
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          id: "ab",
          source: "a",
          target: "b"
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      name: "grid"
    }
  }));

  function makePopper(ele) {
    let ref = ele.popperRef(); // used only for positioning

    ele.tippy = tippy(ref, { // tippy options:
      content: () => {
        let content = document.createElement('div');

        content.innerHTML = ele.id();

        return content;
      },
      trigger: 'manual' // probably want manual mode
    });
  }

  cy.ready(function() {
    cy.elements().forEach(function(ele) {
      makePopper(ele);
    });
  });

  cy.elements().unbind('mouseover');
  cy.elements().bind('mouseover', (event) => event.target.tippy.show());

  cy.elements().unbind('mouseout');
  cy.elements().bind('mouseout', (event) => event.target.tippy.hide());

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* makes sticky faster; disable if you want animated tippies */

.tippy-popper {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.4/cytoscape-popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/umd/index.all.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4.0.1/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```